# Node JS with node-cmd: wait until execution of prior cmd call is finished

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, callback, wait

I have a series of python scripts that I want to call via node-cmd in my Node JS application. They rely on each other, so I cannot execute them in parallel. I also cannot use a fixed waiting time, as they always have different execution time. Right now, upon call of my code, all scripts are called at the same time and therefore error... see my code:

```
pythoncaller: function(req, callback) {

var cmd=require('node-cmd');

cmd.get(`python3 first.py`,
    function(err, data, stderr){
      console.log(err);
      console.log(stderr);
      console.log(data);
});
cmd.get(`python3 second.py`,
    function(err, data, stderr){
      console.log(err);
      console.log(stderr);
      console.log(data);
});

cmd.get(`python3 third.py"`,
    function(err, data, stderr){
      console.log(err);
      console.log(stderr);
      console.log(data);

});
cmd.get(`python3 last.py"`,
    function(err, data, stderr){
      console.log(err);
      console.log(stderr);
      console.log(data);
      callback(data);
});
},
```

Do you know a solution on how to execute those scripts not in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Promisify the callback style functions and use `.then` to execute them one after another. something like this

```
const cmd = require('node-cmd');
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const getAsync = Promise.promisify(cmd.get, { multiArgs: true, context: cmd });

var cmd = require('node-cmd');

getAsync(`python3 first.py`)
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .then(() => getAsync(`python3 second.py`)
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .then(() => getAsync(`python3 third.py"`)
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .then(() => getAsync(`python3 last.py"`)
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

It is also mentioned on `node-cmd` readme. See here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd#with-promises

Answer (score 0):

According to doc, you may promisify `cmd.get`.

Alternative to `.then` with `await` below

```
// copy pasted
// either Promise = require('bluebird') or use (require('util').promisify)
const getAsync = Promise.promisify(cmd.get, { multiArgs: true, context: cmd })

pythoncaller: async function(req, callback) {
  try {
    let data
    data = await getAsync(`python3 first.py`)
    data = await getAsync(`python3 second.py`)
    data = await getAsync(`python3 third.py"`)
    // ...
  } catch (e) {
    return callback(e)
  }
  return callback()
}
```